# Sort By length of array mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB document like below: 
is there a query to Sort the documents with the length of subscribedGroups? which can be ascending or descending.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c29d9ec79d585c0e16b110"), 
    "subscribedGroups" : [
      ObjectId("5b28a9190c8c0d0014b03a0c"), 
      ObjectId("5b2930650b813a0014a3294d"), 
      ObjectId("5b29f1b5243d470014d6d351")
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the size of the `subscribedGroups` using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and then easily [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) with the length of the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      subscribedGroupsLength: {
        $size: "$subscribedGroups"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      subscribedGroupsLength: -1
    }
  }
])
```

See the [sample](https://mongoplayground.net/)

Comment: this is by far better than using old unwind, group, and then sort idea!